# Buildroot Raspberry Pi 3 - No wireless interface

Tags: pi-3, wifi, wireless

I am attempting to get a working buildroot image working on my Raspberry Pi 3 but have run into an issue, I cannot set up a wifi connection.

Running `ifconfig -a` only shows the `eth0` and loopback connections.

I have tested with the stock RP3 build, and can get wifi working on that but I'm not sure where I would look on this to figure out the differences.

I'm not sure what I should be doing to get wifi working.

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: I have attached an image of the wireless related packages I selected within buildroot here:

[image]

Comment: Do you have wifi drivers and firmware?

Comment: Hi Dmitry, I assumed (potentially wrongly) that the above packages would bundle those together if needed. Was I mistaken in that assumption?

Answer (score 0):

The firmware capability will be coming from the kernel.  Where are you getting the kernel from when using buildroot?  It could be that you are using an old kernel that needs to be updated with the firmware for Raspberry Pi 3 (device tree .dtb files under /boot).

A good example of the use of buildroot for Raspberry Pi is berryboot, see the code for it here: https://github.com/maxnet/berryboot

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi John, I have been using the default repo: https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux.git Is there something else that I should be using? Or is there a way that I can add the updated firmware to my current buildroot?

Comment: That looks correct to me and it is also what berryboot does.  Maybe also post the output of 'iwconfig' and/or 'iw list'.

Comment: Here is the output of those: [link](https://imgur.com/pqYnz0w)

Answer (score 0):

John,
Please view my "git clone..." result shown below:
tclee@tclee-Latitude-E6230:~/feb22thu24$ git clone https://github.com/maxnet/berryboot.git
Cloning into 'berryboot'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 26570, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (57/57), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (40/40), done.
error: 7218 bytes of body are still expected MiB | 222.00 KiB/s
fetch-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
fatal: early EOF
fatal: fetch-pack: invalid index-pack output

I am trying to build a Linux with WiFi enabled on rpi3mbb.
FYI, few years ago, before COVID19, I succeeded in this enabling this work with buildroot 2021.02.06.